# What does Purcell mean when he says we can find the average field over some volume by taking surface integrals?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Purcell says that taking the surface integral of the magnetic field $\textbf{B}$ over the surfaces $S_{1}, S_{2},  S_{3},...$ below is a good way of taking the volume integral of $\textbf{B}$ in the neighborhood of these surfaces.
[image]

More specifically, he says in page $553$ of the third edition,

> Now taking the surface integral over a series of equally spaced
> planes like that is a perfectly good way to compute the volume
> average of the field $\textbf{B}$ in that neighborhood, for it samples all volume
> elements impartially.

I can't really see the connection between the volume average of $\textbf{B}$ over, say, the volume between $S_2$ and $S_3$ $$\frac{1}{V}\int \textbf{B}  dv$$ and the surface integrals of $\textbf{B}$ over $S_{3}$ and $S_{2}$ $$\int_{S_3} \textbf{B}\cdot d\textbf{s}_{3},~~\int_{S_2} \textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{s}_{2}.$$ Any indications?

Comment: I cannot find this in *my* Purcell-Morin 3rd edition

Comment: My apologies, I used the wrong page number,  the correct page is $553$.